# How to Automatically Re-Connect Bluetooth HID over GATT (HOG) Device when BlueZ Plugin "hog" is Disabled

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, hid, bluez, bluetooth-gatt

Linux 5.10, BlueZ 5.55

I have a remote control which implements Bluetooth LE. If I use the default Bluetooth daemon, I am able to pair and trust using bluetoothctl. If the connection is lost after a while (or days) and a button on the remote control is pressed, the daemon re-connects automatically (because the device is paired). This is basically what I need.

But, I would also like to manually set notifying for characteristics (Report) on the HID service within my application (Java via d-bus). This is not possible anymore (also not via bluetoothctl) because the "hog" (or "input") plugin manages the input device and the related HID services are now hidden.

I then added "--noplugin=input,hog" to my Bluetooth daemon. Great, now the HID services are available (also using bluetoothctl), but the peripheral does not re-connect automatically anymore. I always have to connect manually first. I also have no signal on the d-bus when I press the button of the remote control, when it is disconnected.

How can I enable automatic re-connect for devices, when these plugins are disabled?

The only other way I was thinking of is to leave the "hog" plugin enabled and use the operating system HID interface. However, my application runs as non-root which makes it complicated and also I would like to have direct connection and control to my device.

Comment: Does your application do `StartDiscovery` from the [Adapter API](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt) when it is not connected to the remote? I suspect the remote is not discoverable until a button is pressed. Once he device is discovered then you know to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Provide Local profile (GATT client) instance [1].

[1] https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/doc/gatt-api.txt#L390